# How do I center text of a cell vertically in a table using VBScript and a word document?

Tags: vbscript

I tried using

```
With myTable.Rows(1) 
 .Height = 20 
 .Cells.VerticalAlignment = wdAlignVerticalTop 
End With
```

But it doesn't seem to work for VBScript, does someone know how to do what I want to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are using vbscript, then vbscript does not know the values of your word enumerated constants. So, either assign values to these constants or just use the numbers/constants directly as shown below:

```
With myTable.Rows(1) 
 .Height = 20 
 .Cells.VerticalAlignment = 1              '1 means WdCellVerticalAlignment(see link below)
End With
```

Click here -- [Word Enumerated constants](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa211923(v=office.11).aspx)

Also, If you are using Word VBA and not vbscript, then you should mention the correct enumerated constant. In your case, It should not be `wdAlignVerticalTop`. Instead, it should be `WdCellVerticalAlignment`.

Comment: Glad I could help :)